# Html <form> and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I made these code:

```
<form>
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="number" id="number7"><br>
          <a href="javascript:calculate()">7</a>
      </div>
      <div class="number" id="number4"><br>
          <a href="javascript:calculate()">4</a>
      </div>
      <div class="number" id="number1"><br>
           <a href="javascript:calculate()">1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="number" id="number0"><br>
            <a href="javascript:calculate()">0</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to get the number into variable in javascript when user click the link?
Any advice would be appreciated! :)
Thank You!

Comment: If you want an interactive control to hang JavaScript off, use a button. Links are supposed to link to places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onclick` and  you can take the text for the event

```js
function calculate(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var number = event.target.innerText;
    console.log(number);
}
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="row1">
    <div class="number" id="number7"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)">7</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number4"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)">4</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number1"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)">1</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number0"><br>
    <a href="" onclick="calculate(event)">0</a></div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: It should be `onclick="calculate"`. `event` in the context of the caller refers to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="row1">
    <div class="number" id="number7"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">7</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number4"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">4</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number1"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">1</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number0"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">0</a></div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Javascript:

```
window.calculate = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var number = parseInt(e.target.innerHTML);
   alert("Number: " + number);
}
```

Though, you should better explore other approaches.

Comment: Don't forget to include this within script tags as well, on your HTML file. If you want to simply get the value, you can also always go with document.GetElementById("NameofElement").value

Answer (score 0):

This example uses a technique known as **event delegation** to reduce the amount of event handlers you need. It also greatly simplifies the use-case for the purposes of your sample code.

As was pointed out in a comment, you shouldn't really be using `a` elements for this, but if you insist then you'll want to set the `href` to `javascript:void(0)` to prevent the browser from trying to navigate.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'A') {
        alert(e.target.innerText);
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="row1">
      <div class="number" id="number7"><br>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">7</a>
      </div>
      <div class="number" id="number4"><br>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">4</a>
      </div>
      <div class="number" id="number1"><br>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="number" id="number0"><br>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">0</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculate(num)
{
    var number = num.target.innerText;
    alert(number);
}
</script>
<form>
    <div class="row1">
    <div class="number" id="number7"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">7</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number4"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">4</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number1"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">1</a></div>
    <div class="number" id="number0"><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="calculate(event)">0</a></div>
    </div>
</form>
```